# Apache Camel to detect manually removed files

Tags: apache, apache-camel, osgi

I know it is possible to use Apache Camel for monitoring newly created files and modified files, but is it possible to detect files deleted manually?
I already checked the specification and could not find anything relevant.

Comment: Can you explain moe about the use case? Is this about the camel file component?

Comment: A use case would be to recursively monitor file changes in the given directory. I know it is not standard feature of Apache Camel, 
but since we use Camel in our project anyway we also wanted to use it to monitor file changes. Unfortunately, to my knowledge, no Exchange is fired when file is deleted.
It is about camel file component indeed.

Comment: I think the camel file component can not help with this case. What do you want to be triggered by the file changes?

Comment: Nothing special, just to execute one method. I just find it odd that Camel does not support such feature.

Comment: I think it is difficult to implement. Especially if you want to recognize files removed while the system is running and while it is not running. You can request the feature on the camel mailing list or jira.

Comment: If you are running on linux, take a look at **inotify** and **sysdig**. With those you can intercept/observe file changes and then trigger some camel route. Unfortunately, there isn't a camel-sysdig component that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this question interesting and implemented `camel-nio2` component, which is based on NIO.2 [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html). Feel free to use it.

**Docs:** https://github.com/bedlaj/camel-nio2

**Example:**

```
from("nio2:/tmp/inputPath?events=ENTRY_DELETE")
    .process(exchange -> {
        FileEvent event = exchange.getIn().getBody(FileEvent.class);
        log.info(event.getEventPath()+" removed");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. We ended up implementing *WatchService* as well. Seems to be best solution so far.